# How to locally test code with tests.py file in the "Check iO" games

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

On the "[Check iO](http://www.checkio.org/)" platform one of the tasks is the simple "[Index Power](http://www.checkio.org/mission/index-power/)" task. As a solution, I wrote the following, working code:

```
def index_power(array, n):
    """
        Find Nth power of the element with index N.
    """
    return array[n] ** n if len(array) > n else -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert index_power([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) == 9, "Square"
    assert index_power([1, 3, 10, 100], 3) == 1000000, "Cube"
    assert index_power([0, 1], 0) == 1, "Zero power"
    assert index_power([1, 2], 3) == -1, "IndexError"
```

For this task, there is a test file for testing localized on the GitHub page. Here's a link => "[test.py](https://github.com/Bryukh-Checkio-Tasks/checkio-mission-index-power/blob/master/verification/tests.py)". This file contains the following code:

```
"""
TESTS is a dict with all you tests.
Keys for this will be categories' names.
Each test is dict with
    "input" -- input data for user function
    "answer" -- your right answer
    "explanation" -- not necessary key, it's using for additional info in animation.
"""

TESTS = {
    "Basics": [
        {
            "input": ([1, 2, 3, 4], 2),
            "answer": 9,
        },
        {
            "input": ([1, 3, 10, 100], 3),
            "answer": 1000000,
        },
        {
            "input": ([0, 1], 0),
            "answer": 1,
        },
        {
            "input": ([1, 2], 3),
            "answer": -1,
        },
    ],
    "Extra": [
        {
            "input": ([0], 0),
            "answer": 1,
        },
        {
            "input": ([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 9),
            "answer": 1,
        },
    ]
}
```

My question is: **Is it possible to test my program on my own computer with that testing file?** If yes, how can I realize and running tests?

Comment: Yes, it is possible - the docstring explains the format of the `TESTS` dictionary. You will have to write a bit of code to iterate through the tests and apply them to your function, but it's not terribly complex.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be complex at all. As jonrsharpe said just iterate through cases.

```
def run_case(input, answer):
    assert index_power(*input) == answer, 'Failed'  # Program stopped on first fail


def test_index_power():
    for level, cases in TESTS.iteritems():  # You can just iterate through dict
        print "Testing level is: %s" % level
        for each in cases:                  # And then through test cases on each level
            run_case(**each)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_index_power()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, especially for ready code! :-)